# React Spring and Styled Components

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, react-spring

I'm new to React, trying to integrate some animations. I'm using Gatsby.js framework.

```
const LeadHeading = styled(animated.h1)`
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-family: ${props => props.theme.fontSecondary};
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 2.5rem;  
  color: #FFF3D8;

const IndexPage = ({menuOpen}) => {

  const h1Animation = useSpring({
    opacity: menuOpen ? '0' : '1'
  })

  return (
    <>
      <Layout>
        <Section className="hero is-fullheight">
          <div className="hero-body container is-flex">
            <LeadHeading 
              style={h1Animation}
            >
              some heading
            </LeadHeading>           
          </div>
        </Section> 
      </Layout>   
    </>
  )
}
export default IndexPage
```

The menu status is managed in the "layout" component via the useState hook.

```
const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false)
```

Basically, I just want to fadeout the h1 when the menu pops up, since it doesn't look good due to the transparency of the menu.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: There is no “props”, you destructured ”menuOpen”.

Comment: sure yeah I ve rewritten some code..still it doesnt work. Sry I cant edit the question

Answer (score 2):

```
const LeadHeading = styled(animated.h1)`
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-family: ${props => props.theme.fontSecondary};
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 2.5rem;  
  color: #FFF3D8;
`


const IndexPage = ({menuOpen}) => {

  const h1Animation = useSpring({
    opacity: menuOpen ? '0' : '1'
  })


  return (
    <>
      <Layout>
        <Section className="hero is-fullheight">
          <div className="hero-body container is-flex">
            <LeadHeading 
              style={h1Animation}
            >
              some heading....
            </LeadHeading>           
          </div>
        </Section> 
      </Layout>   
    </>
  )
}
export default IndexPage
```

EDIT// The menu status is managed in the "layout" component via useState hook. 
But it should be possible, to pass the data to "IndexPage" right?

Ok I thought I can skip the animated part in the render method, since I use it above in the styled component variable. (sry I forgot to mention that in my previous post).
Your approach was one of my first approaches but it didnt work.

Comment: It should work this way as well. But is it work without styled with plain animated.h1? If that is not working the problem is somewhere else in your code or in your config.

Comment: I m using gatsby framework. There is a plugin called 'gatsby-layout-plugin' which supports passing data between "layout" and "pages". https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-layout/